# Cannot Return Chinese Characters From MySql Using Phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, phalcon

I've been trying to get started with Phalcon, but I've been stuck for a few days trying to get query against my database. If I can't find a resolution to this issue I'm going to have to move on.

The target table uses inno-db and is utf-8 encoded. Table has two columns: one is index values, the other is individual (unique) east-Asian characters. When attempting to retrieve a record using a utf-8 encoded Chinese character Phalcon returns 0 records. In addition, when retrieving records using the index value, the corresponding character value is returned as a question mark (a regular question mark, not the question mark browsers use as a placeholder for unrecognized characters).

```
$characters = Characters::find("indCharacter = 乱");
```

Returns this error:

```
"PhalconException: Scanning error before '��' when parsing: SELECT [Characters].* FROM [Characters] WHERE indCharacter = 乱 (64)"
```

Using single quotes around the actual character 0 results are returned.

I've run the exact same queries using the command line, phpmyadmin, and workbench, all of which were in the same environment. All properly returned records.

I've also double checked that the original query value is utf-8 encoded, and that all data in the table is utf-8 encoded.

Phalcon: 1.2.6
Php: 5.4.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Phalcon's Pdo Mysql adapter to create a db connection you have to explicitly set the character encoding. Here is an example similar to one found in Phalcon's tutorial, except that I've added `"charset"`.

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => "myhost",
        "username" => "myusername",
        "password" => "mypassword",
        "dbname" => "mydbname",
        "charset" => "utf8"
    ));
});
```

I had previously looked in the documentation for the various adapter classes, but couldn't find anything relating to setting the encoding for the database connection. I (incorrectly) assumed that encoding detection was handled internally.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:** Just saw your note about single quotes. You could try a parameterised query as below.*

You need to put quotes around the string you're matching. The syntax accepted by `Model::find()` with one parameter is similar to what would normally go in a MySQL WHERE clause.

```
$characters = Characters::find("indCharacter = '乱'");
```

The docs for [finding records](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#finding-records) of a model show this.

#### Parameterised query

Note that you can skip adding quotes and escaping if you use a parameterised query:

```
$characters = Characters::find([
    "indCharacter = :char:",
    'bind' => [
        'char' => '乱'
    ]
]);
```

#### Plain MySQL query

Alternatively, you can run plain MySQL queries using a database adapter. This isn't really suitable if you want to pull model objects from the database, but it does allow you to work around issues with PHQL or skip the ORM when you want to. For example `REGEXP` causes the PHQL parser to error, but it's perfectly valid in MySQL.

```
/** @var Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql $connection */
$connection = $this->di->get('db');
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE indCharacter = '乱'");
```

Answer (score -2):

Small notice... I haven't done anything with Falcon, but I did have a similar error when using MySQL/PHP which I did solve.  Characters like ã and í didn't work.

What you can try it to use Unicode NCRs.  For 乱, it's `&#20081;`.  I found [this](http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html) website that converts Chinese characters to NCRs.

Again, this might work.  My problem was that things were typed into a form and added to a database, which I got around by replacing the instances of characters that didn't work with their NCRs.  It might be a hassle to convert everything but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have no problem retrieving results directly with php. The problem I'm having is that the tools provided by the Phalcon framework are not able to retrieve results.